# Getting SIGSEGV when stack overflow happens in c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

So I recently made a code that handles SIGSEGV signals when it happens, such as when trying to use unitialised pointers. However, for some reason, stack overflows (as indicated by valgrind) fails to call the SIGSEGV signal handler.

Is this standard behavior, or is it just a GCC quirk?

Also, since I've been using backtrace() functionality to figure out what went wrong, would it be right to assume that this won't be accessible because the stack overflow means it won't be possible to get a stack trace (such as the stack too big to print etc)?

It is actually pretty hard to google information about this, as anything related to "stack overflow" goes to this site.

Comment: Catching fatal signals like `SIGSEGV` or `SIGABRT` kind of makes only sense if you are catching them in a parent process.

Comment: "It is actually pretty hard to google information about this, as anything related to "stack overflow" goes to this site." -- try "stack overflow -site:stackoverflow.com" to fix that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as either a stack overflow or a signal in C++, ironically.  So this behavior you see is a platform-specific manifestation of some undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: Ah, I see.. I guess I'll be stuck with valgrind.. thanks. What about double frees? glibc seems to hijack the error handling.

Comment: @Kamziro: I bet it only hijacks the processing in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

It should be impossible to call anything but a systemcall when the stack overflows ,since a functioncall will add more to an overflowed stack.